# Detecting Jar file Tampering

Tags: java, jar

Our scenario is, we have an Exe where in we are bundling some jars and supplying to the Client. We are signing the Exe along with the jars and the META-INF dir holds the checksum values for entries present inside the jar.

Now the issue, when the jar file is tampered like, adding or modifying a class or changing the content, it goes undetected and still the application launches.
But when alongside the corresponding entries ar modified manually in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, the verify signature gets failed and certificate exception is getting thrown. Is there a way, when entries in the jar files are modified (by unzip the jar manually), the corresponding entry in Manifest file is also altered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You say that changes on the jar file are undetected. This is in fact the root of your problem. I don't know how you signed the jar, but java should usually deny loading the jar if the signature that got appended with `jarsigner` doesn't match the contents.